# C# Get the difference between two files and use it for incremental backup

Tags: c#, backup, io

I want to create my own incremental backup solution using C#. How can I obtain the difference between two files (version 1 and version 2 of ABC.TXT) and then update ABC.TXT version 1 with the difference? Would appreciate some hints! Thank you!

Comment: Any reason for writing your own rather than using tried-and-tested existing solutions? It's easy to get this sort of thing subtly wrong, and I assume you care about your data...

Comment: I agree; however I'd still be interested to learn how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I just Googled, might be helpful as a starting point:

[An O(ND) Difference Algorithm for C#](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/ViewSrc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

here are some articles to some diff algorithms explained in C#

[Codeproject 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DiffAlgorithmCS.aspx)

[Codeproject 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx)

Its not easy to get this algorithm right. I would suggest executing kdiff3 or some other good diffing tool in a background process rather than writing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need incremental backup? Is there any reason why you can't just replace version 1 with version 2?

And as Jon pointed, probably you'd better use an already existing and tested backup solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure as to how exactly you would replace the 'difference' text as that could get quite complex. But for the initial checking, you could compare the file sizes.

The link below might help you out:

http://dotnetperls.com/file-size

Comment: Alex is asking about *incremental* backup (just copying the parts of a file that have changed) - knowing the file sizes are different is not much help in this case.